# How to define a Toast style in style.xml?

Tags: android, toast

Can a `Toast` be styled in `style.xml` like we do for Activity themes?

I want to style the following:

- Text color
- Text Size
- Text font
- Background color/opacity
- Background Radius of corners and sizes

I can't find anything that relates to Toast on the web or in the style.xml

**I have solved it by making an StyleableToast class which you can easily use to style your Toasts in almost any way! See answer here:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/39591755/5366495

Comment: I think it is possible. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909476/how-to-customize-toast-in-android) helps.

Comment: @padeg I'm aware of this link. But none of these metion if It can be done in `style.xml`

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18887238/6756523) isn't the way you want to do it?

Comment: @padeg only if its not possible in style.xml

Comment: @padeg I have created an awsome solution. Check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there was not an easy and a non messy way (layouts, inflating etc) to style a `Toast`, I decided then to make a complete `Styleable Toast` class with a lot of styling possibilities!

I will keep improving the `Styleable Toast` class and make it feature rich and release it in the `jCenter()` so it can be added as an `dependency`

Here is it. *Just a single class you put in your project:* https://github.com/Muddz/StyleableToast

**Examples of toasts made with StyleableToast:**

[image]

*All feedback and feature requests is welcome!*

Comment: Hello, the link seems to be broken. Is the project still active?

Comment: Has someone achieved to succesfully integrate this library into your project using the installation instructions provided in his GitHub page? For some reason Android Studio can't load it despite including the implementation on the Gradle module:app file.

Answer (score 3):

why you dont try to make your own toast layout :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View customToastroot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
TextView msg = (TextView) customToastroot.findViewById(R.id.toastMsg);
msg.setText("Speed up !");
msg.setTypeface(tf);
Toast customtoast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
customtoast.setView(customToastroot);
customtoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
customtoast.show();
```

and here is the custom_toast.xml :

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/game_on">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toastMsg"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="Your text"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you .

Comment: This solution will be last resort if its not possible with stye.xml

Comment: i think it's more comfortable to use this solution ,given to the customization you can do with it :)

Comment: Hey again! Check my answer. I have created a `StyleableToast` class which can style a Toast in many was and very easy!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should stop using Toast and look up [SnackBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html). This is the new standard in Material Design guideline way of displaying Toast-type messages.

You can use it similar to a toast but you can also set a  layout for how content should be displayed.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
        .make(coordinatorLayout, "Welcome to AndroidHive", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

snackbar.show();
```

Not only that, you can also set custom interactions like button clicks in the SnackBar. Eg:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
        .make(coordinatorLayout, "Message is deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Message is restored!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar1.show();
            }
        });

snackbar.show();
```

Here is some links to help you apart from documentation.

1) [Material Design guidelines for SnackBar](https://material.google.com/components/snackbars-toasts.html)

2) [SnackBar examples](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/)

I think this is the best way to go as it allows you to do everything that you have asked in your question.

Comment: Hey again! Check my answer. I have created a `StyleableToast` class which can style a Toast in many was and very easy!

Comment: I think your class is a better answer as long as you don't want interactions. But with Snackbar you can have interactions like button clicks as well. And also you can have the SnackBar move with CoordinatorLayout. I feel this was a better way to go if you wanted Toast messages to do something more than just UI display.

Comment: Hi. I just wanted a beutifull toast for my apps, to show small important messages, not actions or buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I created my own class for that. Because it prevents me from trouble I experienced from other peoples solutions.
This is how it looks:

[image: Example]

You can show a Toast simple in a single row:

```
MyToast.showShort(context, getString(R.string.verworfen));
MyToast.showLong(context, getString(R.string.verworfen));
```

//Code

```
public class MyToast{

    private static Toast currentToast;

    public static void showShort(Context context, String message){
        if(currentToast != null) currentToast.cancel();
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.root));
        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.message);

        text.setText(message);

        Toast toast = new Toast(context);

        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
        currentToast = toast;
    }

    public static void showLong(Context context, String message){
        if(currentToast != null) currentToast.cancel();
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.root));
        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.message);

        text.setText(message);

        Toast toast = new Toast(context);

        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
        currentToast = toast;
    }

    public static Toast getCurrentToast(){
        return currentToast;
    }

}
```

//Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_toast">

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

//Drawable

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"   >

    <solid
        android:color="@color/primary_dark" >
    </solid>

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/primary_light" >
    </stroke>

    <padding
        android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"    >
    </padding>

    <corners
        android:radius="11dp"   >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

Comment: I have made a class that handles all this in a very simple way and yet makes it very easy to style Toasts with a lot of different styling attributes. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Styling Toast, or more specifically `setView()` was deprecated in Android 11 (API 30). Google does not want every app to have different toast style.

If you want a custom toast, you will have to implement and show your custom view, that looks like a toast.

Imo, you shouldn't do it and use default toast without any custom style, like it was intended by Google.